# Prevent infinite recursion in c++

Tags: c++

So, I'm triying to learn c++ (coming from python), and I wanted to make a program just to see if i could do it with what i've learned, here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int response(string i) {
    if (i == "yes" or i == "Yes") {
        cout << "\nHello, sad, I'm dad\n";
        return(0);
    }
    else if (i == "no" or i == "No") {
        cout << "Good for you pal\n";
        return(0);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Answer properly you overgrown flatworm\n";
        response(i);
    };
};

int main() { 
    string i;
    cout << "Are you sad?";
    cin >> i;
    response(i);
};
```

Pretty simple huh? No. For some reason, yes and no answers work fine, but when I try something different I get insulted infinitely and the program crashes from exceeding it's memory limit. How do I solve this?
(English is not my native language, so feel free to correct any ortography mistakes)

Comment: Tip: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables especially when you’re importing a lot of header files which may define a lot more things than they superficially appear to.

Comment: you're getting a stack overflow exception since the else case calls response method with no changes, what you want in that case I believe is to prompt the user again to provide a different input

Comment: Instead of using recursion, use a loop. This is not a problem that requires recursion at all.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Just fixed it, forgot to add it while triying to fix the problem

Comment: Have you walked through the code? The good news is that the string of insults tells you which code path execution follows, so you just have to go step-by-step to see why it follows that path.

Comment: Wnen the response is not `"Yes"` or `"No"`, the same response is passed to the recursive call.   So the recursion will be infinite.   To avoid infinite recursion, the value needs to be changed somehow before the recursive call.    Also, it is necessary (when recursively calling `response()`) to return the value from the recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by eliminating recursion ad it involves moving the input routine inside of a function that's more self-contained:

```
int getResponse(string i) {
  for(;;) {
    string i;
    cout << "Are you sad?";
    cin >> i;

    if (i == "yes" or i == "Yes") {
        cout << "\nHello, sad, I'm dad\n";
        return(0);
    }
    else if (i == "no" or i == "No") {
        cout << "Good for you pal\n";
        return(0);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Answer properly you overgrown flatworm\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @cigien Fixed and moved that into the routine. The original code had the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

At no point do you request further input.  For bad input 'i', the response routine prints out an insult, and then calls itself with exactly the same string.

The response routine prints out an insult, and then calls itself with exactly the same string.

The response routine prints out an insult, and then calls itself with exactly the same string.

…

You need to allow the user to enter a new string, and then (if you want to use recursion) make the recursive call to validate the new input.

But as mentioned in the comment, this is not really a problem that needs a recursive solution.

Comment: You pretty much nailed it.

Comment: You also need to `return` the result of the recursive call, otherwise it's UB.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues:

In the `else` case, you are not asking for new user input.

You need to return the result of calling `response(i)`, otherwise the code invokes undefined behavior.

```
else {
    cout << "Answer properly you overgrown flatworm\n";
    cin >> i;   
    return response(i);
};
```

---

Alternatively, since you never use the return value from `response`, you can just remove all the `return` statements, and make it a `void` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using recursion then move the input and the check in the same function `response()` - that function doesn't need to return `int` at all.  In `main` you can just call `response()`.

```
void response()
{
    string i;
    cout << "Are you sad?";
    cin >> i;
    if (i == "yes" or i == "Yes")
    {
        cout << "\nHello, sad, I'm dad\n";
    }
    else if (i == "no" or i == "No")
    {
        cout << "Good for you pal\n";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Answer properly you overgrown flatworm\n";
        response();
    }
}

int main()
{
    response();
}
```

Comment: I admit I'm a bit tired, but the advice to "_move the input and the check in the same function `response()`_"  with the addition "_that function doesn't need to return `int` at all. In `main` you can just call `response()`_" doesn't help me. I see you code. Perhaps you should explain what you did to make it work (for a limited number of tries - and why it's limited)?

Comment: It's limited try because when the answer is "yes" or "no" then there is no more recursive call. Otherwise it's recursive and keep asking for user input. I suggested having `void response()` as the return value is never really needed from OP code.

Comment: Perhaps an ASCII drawing of the y/n possibilities? ... I just suggested that you do the work I was thinking of :-) I'll leave you to it and do something else in the meantime. Sorry for planting.

Comment: Sorry not that good with ASCII drawing, and the problem doesn't require such a thing. Just testing it works.